# How to dynamically add parameters to firestore query and map to object

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

**What is the recommended way to map the data to an object and return it as a promise/observable while being able to add dynamic/conditional parameters to the query.**

In getCompanies2 I can dynamically add parameters to the query but I can't figure out how to map the data returned to my object and return it as a promise/observable.

In getCompanies everything works as I want it but I have to duplicate the code (as below) if I have dynamic query parameters to add.

Note: convertDocTimeStampsToDate just does what it says.  I have excluded it to reduce the size of the code section.

```
getCompanies(searchText: string, useWhereActive: boolean): Observable<Company[]> {
    if (useWhereActive) {
      return this.db.collection('companies', ref => ref
      .orderBy('name').startAt(searchText).endAt(searchText + '\uf8ff')
      .where('active', '==', true)
    )
      .snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
        map(snaps => convertSnaps<Company>(snaps)),
        first()
      );
    } else {
      return this.db.collection('companies', ref => ref
      .orderBy('name').startAt(searchText).endAt(searchText + '\uf8ff')
    )
      .snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
        map(snaps => convertSnaps<Company>(snaps)),
        first()
      );
    }
  }
​
getCompanies2(searchText: string, useWhereActive: boolean) {
    let query = this.db.collection('companies').ref
      .orderBy('name').startAt(searchText).endAt(searchText + '\uf8ff');
​
    if (useWhereActive) {
      query.where('active', '==', true);
    }
​
    query.get().then(querySnapshot => {
      const results = this.convertDocuments<Company>(querySnapshot.docs);
      console.log(results);
    });
}


convertDocuments<T>(docs) {
    return <T[]>docs.map(doc => {
      return {
        id: doc.id,
        ...doc.data()
      };
    });
}

export function convertSnaps<T>(snaps) {
  return <T[]>snaps.map(snap => {
    const data = convertDocTimeStampsToDate(snap.payload.doc.data());
    return {
      id: snap.payload.doc.id,
      ...data
    };
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work like below, I guess I am still getting my head around promises.

Any better solutions will be accepted though as I am still learning and don't know if this is the best method.

```
getCompanies2(searchText: string, useWhereActive: boolean) {
    let query = this.db.collection('companies').ref
      .orderBy('name').startAt(searchText).endAt(searchText + '\uf8ff');

    if (useWhereActive) {
      query.where('active', '==', true);
    }

    return query.get().then(querySnapshot => {
      return this.convertDocuments<Company>(querySnapshot.docs);
    });
  }
```